# How can prove this ineqaulity $||x^{\delta}_{n}-R_{n}y||\le a_{n}|\alpha^{\delta}-\alpha|$

Tags: real-analysis

> prove that:
>   $$||x^{\delta}_{n}-R_{n}y||\le a_{n}|\alpha^{\delta}-\alpha|$$
>   where
>   $$x^{\delta}_{n}-R_{n}y=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\alpha^{\delta}_{j}-\alpha_{j})x_{j}$$
>   $$a_{n}=\max{\{||\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}x_{j}||:\sum_{j=1}^{n}|p_{j}|^2=1\}}$$
>   $$\alpha^{\delta}-\alpha=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\alpha^{\delta}_{j}-\alpha_{j})^2}$$

my idea:
$$||x^{\delta}_{n}-R_{n}y||=\sup{\dfrac{||(x^{\delta}_{n}-R_{n}y)*(p)||}{||p||}}
=||\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\alpha^{\delta}_{j}-\alpha_{j})x_{j}p_{j}||$$
use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,we have 
$$||\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\alpha^{\delta}_{j}-\alpha_{j})x_{j}p_{j}||\le \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\alpha^{\delta}_{j}-\alpha_{j})^2}\cdot \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_{j}p_{j})^2}\le a_{n}|\alpha^{\delta}-\alpha|$$
where
$$p=(p_{1},p_{2},\cdots,p_{n}),||p||=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{n}|p_{j}|^2}$$

This methods true or false? because my teacher say this solution has some mistake, I hope someone can help.Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proof might work but it is a little sloppy when you define $\Vert x_n^\delta - R_n y\Vert$ as $\sup_p \Vert (x_n^\delta - R_n y)*p\Vert/\Vert p \Vert$ then skip the sup and then assume $\Vert p \Vert = 1$ without precising it. I think it is simpler to write
$$ \Vert x_n^\delta - R_ny \Vert = \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n (\alpha_j^\delta - \alpha_j)^2 x_j^2} = \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n \Vert \alpha^\delta - \alpha \Vert^2 \frac{(\alpha_j^\delta - \alpha_j)^2}{\Vert \alpha^\delta - \alpha \Vert^2} x_j^2}= \Vert \alpha^\delta - \alpha \Vert \Vert \sum_{j=1}^n  p_j x_j \Vert, $$
where $p_j := \frac{(\alpha_j^\delta - \alpha_j)}{\Vert \alpha^\delta - \alpha \Vert}$ satisfies $\sum_{j=1}^n p_j^2 = 1$.